# JS Can I somehow get instance of class by name if the classes are inside closure?

Tags: javascript, reflection, closures, environment, classloading

I'm working on a plugin system for mine service, and I load the plugins code from text using the **new Function()** construction. And I need somehow get access to the classes constructors link outside the plugin code. (for testing, *unit tests*)

Here is, I see a few solutions (if you know another solution, I'm open to your idea).

1. add link to classes in the window object (global env)
2. return the classes list as a result of loading and provide to the place where I need to use it.

The second one it too complicated for testing and required change the entire app for testing, that is not perfect.
The first one creates one more global variable that is not perfect as well, but it's ok for testing environment (so for now I've chosen this solution).

The next question, how to do it reusable for any plugin (the class provider for testing env) should not depend on the specific plugin classes, but the plugin can depend on some function, and we can specify the correct plugin code structure.

I suppose that I could be done by using something like this (much simplified version):

```
function getClassInstanceFactoryMethod(){

   class A{
   }

   class B{
   }

   return (className, params)=>{
      return new className(...params); //need somehow choose the correct class and avoid the switch construction or manual collection in an array. 
   }
}

const buildObject = getClassInstanceFactoryMethod();
let objeA = buildObject('A');  //expected object of the A class 
let objeA = buildObject('B');  //expected object of the B class
```

But the problem is avoided, enumeration of plugins class list (load it automatically).

Please any idea how to do it.

Comment: `const classes = { A, B }; return new classes[className](…);`…?

Comment: Yes it's probably a solution but in this case we need to create a list (enumeration) of existing classes that I'd like to avoid because sometimes plugins can consist more of 200 classes.

Comment: Note that this approach would be *very* brittle. It very tightly couples the callers of this factory to the actual implementation, thus losing much of the benefit of having a factory. If the caller has to know the precise internal name  that needs to be created, that means that changing the implementation is not feasible. The regular way is for the caller to indicate to the factory what's needed (e.g., by passing an enum) then the factory decides what class to actually construct. This allows for `factory("foo")` to return, for example, a subclass without the caller needing to change.

Comment: In the main topic, it's about to getting an instance of a class outside the function. For unit tests, so it's ok if unit test will use something like this. 
I called it factory in the example to simplify understanding what I need 

In any case, thanks for the potential problem highlighting.